# Why NavigationBar is not transparent?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I wrote the code:

```
if let navigationBar = self.navigationController?.navigationBar {
        navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
        navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
        navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
        navigationBar.backItem?.hidesBackButton = true
    }
```

it works on previous screen, but after the segue it does not. It looks like:

[image]

it's gray color, not transparent and I do not know why this happens. But on the previous screen, with the SAME code I get this result:

[image]

Is there any idea what happens there?

Comment: I think you are missing some relevant code parts in your question

Comment: `isTranlucent` is the opposite of "transparent". Try setting `isTranslucent = false`.

Comment: @dfd - I think "opaque" is the opposite of "transparent".

Comment: Maybe not the opposite (and for being less than 100% accurate I do apologize) but neither is *translucent* the *same* as *transparent*.